# Hamburger menu spin to arrow on new activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-animation, hamburger-menu

I've noticed that with the more recent Gmail updates for Android, when you click on one of your emails, a new Activity opens (I'm assuming it's not a fragment because of the back arrow).

The new activity's back arrow does not just appear as they do by default, however. The **hamburger menu from the main interface spins into an arrow** in an animation (see the video here: http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B3T7oTWa3HiFbFRfT196SWRyS2s/animation_delightfuldetails_wellcrafted.webm)

(Note: The newly opened email MAY be a fragment, because the toolbar doesn't change & the default new activity animation doesn't play. I'm not sure which one it is.)

Clarification: I do know how to get the hamburger menu to turn into an arrow when it's pressed/when the navigation drawer is opened. In fact, I purposefully disabled said animation because it goes against specs. (see this article: http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/30/google-turns-design-inconsistency-ten-latest-round-navigation-drawers/). I want to know, however, **if the same animation is possible when creating a new fragment/activity**, whichever one Gmail probably uses.

Comment: In my opinion GMail is using fragments. Here you can find menu drawer template with spining arrow: https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template .

Answer (score 0):

If you use  `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` it animates automatically.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it animates automatically, at least when you pull open the navigation drawer. But I want to know if I can trigger the animation when I create a new activity/fragment

Comment: Any news on this issue? Can't seem to find anything else

Answer (score 0):

It too late but i put it here for upcoming questions.
Gmail app opens email in a fragment.Cause you can still use hamburger menu in this page.Changing hamburger menu icon to back button i use this code and it works fine.

```
  public void setupToolbarNavigation() {
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onBackPressed();
            reverseToolbar();


        }
    });
}

 public void reverseToolbar() {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(null);
}
```

toggle is instance of ActionBarDrawerToggle which you can initiate it with this code in your activity

```
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
```

reverseToolbar change toolbar back icon to hamburger menu icon when user clicked.Declare this method in your activity and for replacing icon in fragment put this code to your fragment. ((YourActivity)getActivity()).setupToolbarNavigation