# Activity to activity transition

Tags: android, hamburger-menu

In android, I go from one Activity which has a hamburger icon to second Activity which has an arrow button. I want to make an animation, where the hamburger icon rotates in style to arrow button. How can this be done?

Comment: Look into the Transition Framework, https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations/blob/master/README.md . You will create a shared element.

Comment: am speaking similar to gmail. when i click on a message, the top hamburger icon changes to arrow icon in animation style  ( spinny arrow).

Comment: same question here but no answer given yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775234/hamburger-menu-spin-to-arrow-on-new-activity